# Is there a way to receive outgoing messages through webhook? (Official Whatsapp Business API)

Tags: webhooks, whatsapp, facebook-webhooks, whatsapi, whatsapp-cloud-api

I´m testing the official WhatsApp Business API by Meta, and want to receive the messages that i send to the users through the webhook, because the logic on my program manage the messages that way (I´ve been using Ultramsg and they send a webhook event whenever i send a message to a user).

Could be because i´m using the test phone number provided by meta, or is it always like that?

I tried subscribing to every webhook event available but none of those seem to send the object that i need.

Comment: you need to refer to [this article](https://www.mongodb.com/developer/products/atlas/whatsapp-business-api-data-api/) for more details.

Answer (score -1):

I found out that you need to susbcribe to message_echoes on the webhook events to receive the messages that you send to users through webhook.

Comment: Hey Caleb. Did you get it working? I'm getting an error when I try to subscribe to that event: `Failed to subscribe to the message_echoes v19.0`